# update large file in chunk using google-drive

Tags: curl, oauth-2.0, google-drive-api

I upload a large file in chunk with CURL, I've got my upload URI and everything is OK.

5 minutes before my access_token expires, I create a new one if I have a service account or I use the refresh token with a user account.
I use the new one in my PUT requests.

Despite this, 5 minutes later I've got the 401 error. Is there a way to bypass this problem?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, this problem is on the Google Drive endpoint and can't be fixed in your code.

Some guy filed [an issue about this](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-python-client/issues/detail?id=231) at Jan 13, 2013, and more than one year has passed, it seems no updates from Google about this, and others still meet this problem.

> This is an issue with the backend and not with the API or with your code. As you deduced, if the upload goes too long the access_token expires and at that point the resumable upload can't be continued. There is work on progress to fix this issue right now, I will update this bug once the issue is fixed on the server side.

And here's [another report](https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=5124) about this issue.

Comment: Hi Owen, thanks for your answer. 
It seems a little strange that Google doesn't fix this bug.